# Changing directory structure of a project in TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, projects-and-solutions, source-control-explorer

Problem:
Need to remove a redundant level of directories in a project in TFS. It is only visible in TFS source control - not in Visual Studio's solution explorer.

VS Solution browser shows what you'd expect:

Solution - Project1 - files etc as expected.

But TFS Source Control Explorer shows this:

Solution - Project1 - Project1 - files etc as expected.

I can't remove the extra directory level via Visual Studio since I can't see it there. Creating other directories in TFS directly and moving files around is a huge mess where it's hard to avoid breaking our automated builds in the process. Can I simply edit the project and solution files after moving my local files around?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete the redundant folder in Source Control Explorer that means you need to change structure in TFS. No matter which method you use, it will affect the builds because Source Control Explorer gets files from TFS and your TFS builds also get files from TFS. If it doesn't affect you very much, I don't suggest deleting it.

If you do want to delete the redundant folder and you don't want to use move action in Source Control Explorer, you could to do the following:

```
Solution Folder - Project Folder1 - Project Folder2
```

1. In Solution Explorer, remove the Project1.
2. Then **cut** Project Folder2 to under Solution Folder.
3. In Solution Explorer, re-add Project1.
4. In Source Control Explorer, Delete/Remove Solution - Project Folder1 and files in it.
5. Right-click Solution Folder and choose **Add Existing item** to add the Folder to Cut in Step2.
6. Check in.